# Power generation strategy

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply

For a new board I will be building, I will need to generate the following power values:

The current values are max values. In parenthesis, I included the approximate duty cycles.

- 3.3V Analog - 150mA - (100%)
- 1.2V Digital - 700mA - (10%)
- 2.5V Analog - 700mA - (10%)
- 12V Digital - 100mA - (5%)
- 3.3V Digital - 500mA - (100%)
- 2V Digital - 10mA - (100%)

My input is a single cell li-poly battery.

- When I should cut off the battery drain? What is the best practice? 3V, 3.2V, 3V? This potentially has some impact on power generation. If I set this 3.4V, I can get rid of the booster for 4.5V I mention below and use LDOs that are directly tied to the battery.
- What is the common sense (expert opinion) power generation strategy in this case?

I was thinking

```
li-ion --> Booster --> 4.5V
li-ion --> Booster --> 12V

4V --> LDO --> 3.3V Analog
4V --> LDO --> 3.3V Digital
3.3V --> LDO --> 1.2V Digital
```

etc. Basically, generate two main voltages using booster and use LDOs to drop down.

I updated the question added a few details but removed the definition of best. I can probably manage to optimize for cost or power efficiency, rather I am looking for wisdom. An expert opinion that includes pitfalls I haven't thought of.

Comment: What is your goal for "best"? Most efficient? Smallest? Cheapest?

Comment: As written, question is very specific; I would expect it to be closed.

Comment: You didn't mention 2 V digital in your initial solution. Were you planning an LDO from 3.3 V digital?

Comment: @BrianCarlton question is indeed specific however this is great learning for the inexperienced guy. I haven't done many system designs and I can make it more generic however I believe this is a good, if not great question

Comment: @BrianCarlton I am looking for a general direction, not a specific answer.

Comment: If you want efficiency you need to use a switcher for each of them. Especially the LDOs to go from 4V to 1.2V at 700mA are a disaster: efficiency is 30%; power loss 2W.

Comment: @stevenvh that would be one noisy board. But I got what you are saying.

Comment: Linear has low-voltage synchronous switchers with up to 4 outputs. Maybe those are less noisy than 4 separate ones. Won't be cheap though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various supplies going off 4.5 V. Assuming a LDO to get 3.3 V digital and analog, instead pick a voltage for 4.5 V that is just above the minimum drop-out of those two LDO. For example if they have a drop-out of 300 mV, I would use 3.3 V + 0.3 V = 3.6 V, probably using 3.7 for some margin.

For 3.6 V (Li Ion) to 12 V @ 100 mA there are a variety of switchers with internal FET from [TI](http://webench.ti.com/webench5/power/webench5.cgi?lang_chosen=en_US&VinMin=3&VinMax=3.7&O1V=12&O1I=.1&op_TA=30) in the ~150 mm and ~$1 range. The linked page lets you choose based on efficiency, cost and size.

Current from 3.3 V (digital) to digital rails is 700 mA (1.2 V), 500 mA (3.3 V) and 10 mA (2.0 V). That's 1.21 A input into the 3.3 V LDO (from 4.5 V) and 1.45 W lost. I would consider a switcher for 1.2 V. Or an LDO from the input, rather than 3.3 V.

Be careful with your sequencing, especially when using switchers. Some parts require power to come up in a specific order.

Comment: Good catch on the 1.2V. LDO from the battery directly makes sense.